# Сериализация в JSON как объект конкретного класса

Tags: java, gson

Есть у меня объект такого класса

```
class A {
  List<BaseClass> items;
}
```

Я хочу его сериализовать в JSON. Пишу

```
A obj;
........
gson.toJson(obj);
```

Проблема: в `items` могут хранится как объекты `BaseClass`, так и его наследников. И Gson сериализует **все** поля этих объектов.

Вопрос: нельзя ли как-то указать Gson сериализовать только поля, относящиеся к `BaseClass` и его предкам. А поля наследников не трогать?

P.S. Наследники участвуют в сериализации других классов

Comment: А как вы хотите определить какие поля вам надо?

Comment: А Вы пробовали объявить не нужные поля transient?

Comment: @Vanguard В том то и дело, что поля нужные. Но для сериализации  других классов

Comment: @RomanC нужны все поля опеределенные в классе BaseClass и его предков. И не нужны все поля, определенные в наследниках BaseClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** Или еще более простой вариант.

Реализуем сериализатор для любого `List`

```
public class GenericListSerializer implements JsonSerializer<List> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(List src, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonArray res = new JsonArray();
        if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            ParameterizedType paramType = (ParameterizedType)type;
            Type[] args = paramType.getActualTypeArguments();
            type = args[0];
        }
        for (Object item : src) {
            JsonObject currentItem = (JsonObject)context.serialize(item, type);
            res.add(currentItem);
        }
        return  res;
    }
}
```

А теперь помечаем поля специальной аннотацией

```
class A {
  @JsonAdapter(GenericListSerializer.class)
  List<BaseClass> items;
}
```

Все. теперь при сериализации поля `items` будет вызываться сериализатор `GenericListSerializer`

---

**Old version**

Получился такой адаптер:

```
public class CustomSerializer implements JsonSerializer<A> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(A src, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        // Сериализуем поля родителя без изменений
        JsonObject res = (JsonObject)context.serialize(src, src.getClass().getSuperclass());
        // Получаем свои поля
        Field[] flds = src.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field fld : flds) {
            Type fldType = fld.getGenericType();
            JsonElement jField;
            Object fieldVal;
            try {
                // Получаем значение поля
                fieldVal = fld.get(src);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            // Если тип поля List и его наследники и это generic-тип
            if (fld.getType().isAssignableFrom(List.class) && fldType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                // Получаем конкретные типы, которые были указаны в объявлении List<>
                ParameterizedType paramType = (ParameterizedType)fldType;
                Type[] args = paramType.getActualTypeArguments();
                // формируем массив
                JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
                for (Object item : (List)fieldVal) {
                    // сериализуем элемент списка, как тип, который был указан при объявлении
                    JsonObject currentItem = (JsonObject)context.serialize(item, args[0]);
                    jsonArray.add(currentItem);
                }
                jField = jsonArray;
            }
            else {
                // Если у нас не список, то вызываем умолчательный сериализатор
                jField = context.serialize(fieldVal);
            }
            res.add(fld.getName(), jField);
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Определяем свои правила конвертации объектов `Gson`

`Gson` позволяет разработчикам определять свои собственные правила для сериализации и десериализации объектов. Зарегистрировать их можно с помощью метода `registerTypeAdapter()`.

Для класса `A()`:

```
class A {
    List<BaseClass> items;
}
```

Предположим, что `BaseClass` имеет одно поле:

```
class BaseClass {
    String field;
}
```

тогда создадим класс `CustomSerializer` и имплиментируем там соответствующий интерфейс:

```
public class CustomSerializer implements JsonSerializer<A> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(A src, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonArray items = new JsonArray();

        for (BaseClass item : src.items) {
            if (item.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("BaseClass")) {
                JsonObject currentItem = new JsonObject();
                currentItem.addProperty("field", item.field);
                items.add(currentItem);
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

***Примечание:** класс сериализатор будет содержать только объекты типа `BaseClass`, чтобы он содержал еще и его предков, нужно добавить дополнительное условие.*

После этого регистрируем наш кастомный сериализатор:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(A.class, new CustomSerializer());
Gson gson = builder.create();
```

Теперь можно смело вызывать метод

```
A obj;
........
gson.toJson(obj);
```

---

Для дерериализации аналогично создаем класс `CustomDeserializer` и имплиментируем там соответствующий интерфейс.

Сперва добавим конструкторы для классов `A` и `BaseClass`:

```
class A {
    List<BaseClass> items;

    A(ArrayList<BaseClass> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}

class BaseClass {
    String field;

    BaseClass(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
}
```

Теперь создаем класс `CustomDeserializer`:

```
public class CustomDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<A> {

    @Override
    public A deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonArray items = (JsonArray) json;

        A a = new A(new ArrayList<>());

        for (JsonElement item : items) {
            JsonObject currentItem = new JsonObject();
            BaseClass baseClass = new BaseClass(item.getAsString());
            a.items.add(baseClass);
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

и регистрируем его аналогичным образом:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(A.class, new CustomDeserializer());
Gson gson = builder.create();
```

---

### Внимание:

Если используется одновременно и сериализатор, и десериализатор, тогда нужно создать один класс, в котором имплементировать оба интерфейса, т.к. последовательная регистрация разных классов методом `registerTypeAdapter` будет переписывать предыдущую регистрацию.

Comment: `if (item.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("BaseClass")) {` еще раз - мне нужно не сериализовать объекты определенного класса, а сериализовать все объекты как определенный класс. Т.е. в Json должны попасть все объекты любых классов, но без полей, объявленных в наследниках `BaseClass`

Comment: Спасибо. Благодаря Вашему пинку было найдено простое и красивое решение